# Node 12 (v8) - converting deprecated code to the "maybe" version

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I decided to update Node to 12.11. Because of this, I'm getting gyp compilation errors in some node modules that I'm using. I have some experience with C++, but I've never used v8. I've managed to fix most errors related to previously deprecated and now removed functions, but there's one kind of a problem that I'm unable to solve:

```
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = size->ToObject();
if(obj->Has(columns))
    w->ws_col = obj->Get(columns)->Uint32Value();
if(obj->Has(rows))
    w->ws_row = obj->Get(rows)->Uint32Value();
```

`ToObject()` has been removed, so I came up with this:

```
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = Nan::To<v8::Object>(size).ToLocalChecked();
```

The problem is that there's no `v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)` method. How can I make the `Has` calls compatible with the new version?

Comment: Are you sure that those modules are not compatible with node 12? Sometimes the problem is that you didn't do a clean reinstall of the modules after you updated node.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I'm absolutely sure. I'm using [spectcl](https://github.com/spectcl/spectcl) which depends on [child_pty](https://github.com/Gottox/child_pty) and [termios](https://github.com/jerch/node-termios). These projects are probably abandoned and won't be updated any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-deprecated replacement for the old `ToObject()` is `MaybeLocal<Object> v8::Value::ToObject(Local<Context> context)`; using `Nan` is certainly possible but not required. Note that `.ToLocalChecked` will trigger a crash if an exception was thrown and there is no result value, this can happen e.g. if you call this function on `null` or `undefined`. The result type `MaybeLocal` is intended to make it obvious that embedder code needs to check for this, and handle exceptions as appropriate.

Similarly, the non-deprecated versions of `Has()` are the two that take context parameters: `Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key)` and `Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index)`. The `Maybe<bool>` they return is nothing (`.IsNothing() == true`) if an exception was thrown, otherwise it's a `bool` with the result.